# dynamically enable textbox from dropdownlist selection by db row

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

im trying to make a dynamically enable textbox based on selection from dropdownlist..the row of dropdown list will be generated based on how many rows i have in db..the problem now is my script only work only for the first textbox in the first row..i have no idea how to make it dynamically enabled based on row..thnx in advance

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckValue(val){
 var element=document.getElementById('justify');
 if(val=='1'||val=='5')
   element.disabled=false;
  else  
   element.disabled=true;
 }
 </script>
```

my select menu and textbox

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

echo '<td><select id="languageEva1" name="languageEva1[]" style="width:60px;float:left;" class="form-control" onchange="CheckValue(this.value);">
        <option value="" selected></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select></td>';
 echo '<td><input type="text" name="justify[]" id="justify" class="form-control" disabled/></td>';

 }
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one DOM Element with the same `id` i.e. `id="justify"` it wont complain loudly, but as an id is supposed to be unique you then dont know what you are addressing in the `document.getElementById('justify')` code

Comment: so,how can i make it work? im sorry im very2 new in php and i did not really know how to manipulate javascript

Comment: I would start with a Google Search for `simple html tutorial` then another using `simple javascript tutorial` or head to the library and read a few books